# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token

Tags: c++

I have some `extern`'d variables in a namespace in a header file, and I'm trying to initialize them in its corresponding cpp file. However, I keep getting the error given in the topic title. I'm not sure what the problem is.

EX:

```
// Some header
namespace foo
{
    extern SDL_Surface* bar;
}

// In the impl file
#include "someheader.h"
foo::bar = 0;
.....
```

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to initialize a pointer to an invalid pointer representation (NULL)?  Why?

Comment: if you put that outside the namespace does it works ?

Comment: @Ed that's just to check if the things was initialized that's ok, it would need a cast BTW

Comment: @Ed Because leaving it uninitialized is a step down the slippery slope to undefined behavior. I.e. if someone tried to use it and it wasn't initialized something very bad could happen.

Comment: @RageZ I have done something similar in the past without a namespace and it has worked.

Comment: And no if I take them out of the namespace it doesn't work. Odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the file level, you can only define types (you've only written an assignment expression). So you need to change that to:

```
SDL_Surface* foo::bar = 0;
```

Comment: Or he would have to move that statement within any of the functions.

Comment: @Technowise - the problem is he will then be lacking a definition of the variable and the linker will fail with a missing symbol.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know what type SDL_Surface is. You need to define it or at least forward declare it.

Comment: The example was just an example, not the actual code. I can assure you it knows what an SDL_Surface is. I'll edit the example to be more clear.